# Accordion menu - in place navigation

Tags: html, user-interface, menu, navigation, accordion

I am very new to web development and I am trying to create a navigation menu for my users to reach the correct help channel.
I looked at accordion menus but I would like to have an effect similar to the Google Play Help contact us [menu](https://support.google.com/googleplay/?hl=en#topic=3364260&contact=1) (top right), where the new layer substitutes and hides the previous.

Could anyone point me in the right direction in terms of web structures to do so? Google seems to use their own API to do it so I couldn`t get much by inspecting the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking into something similar, I ended up creating a series a buttons and updating them on click.